# Installing Javascript client library via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to Node.js (which I'm assuming this is; I'm so new that I'm not really understanding what's going on here). I'm working with a client library for a system called RJ Metrics. I'm basically tying their API in with a Volusion API in order to import data into their system from the Volusion site. The code for that all makes sense but I'm not understanding how to install it and use it.

Their [documentation is here](http://developers.rjmetrics.com/libraries.html):

And I'm needing to use the Javascript library because I'm working with Volusion which is on a Windows server and there is no ASP/C# option here. It says `The RJMetrics Javascript client library is available via npm:` and then terminal code. After research, it appeared that this uses Node.js so I installed that on my computer and ran the npm install rjmetrics in the Terminal which succeeded. I was assuming though that I must have to log into their server and run the code in order to get it to work.

Does this require me to SSH into the server? Am I way off base and is there a way I can just include some JS files in my page? I looked at their GitHub too and all of the main files use the require() function in them which I'm gathering is a Node.js function?

Apologies if I'm way off, I'm into this up to my neck and just trying to sort it all out now.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the documentation (to which you refferred) is just plain ol' javascript. though NPM is the node package manager. So if you want, it looks like you can just run this .js script in a web browser like any other.

```
var rjmetrics = require("rjmetrics");
client = rjmetrics.Client(api_key, client_id);

# do stuff with client
```

If you wanted to do it in Node, you would create a .js file on your machine with their API code inside of it doing whatever you want. Then in terminal you run the script by going "node myfile.js". A local webserver setup is all you need to create and test this.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried that but require() doesn't work without some sort of library also on the server.

Comment: oh ok, then I would go with Node. Their examples are all written like nodejs scripts.

Comment: So yeah that's the original question. I don't know how to use Node I guess. How do I install it? How do I use it? That's the basis of my question.

Comment: Oh sorry, so in your question you said you installed node already, so now all you need to do is write some javascript in a .js file and run that from terminal using "node myFile.js" and that will execute it. Node isn't a different language, there are lots of modules you can install through NPM to help you on your project but it's just plain javascript.